# If conditional for multiple raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arctoolbox

I have 12 raster on NDVI. I want to use if conditional statement. Something like this :

```
Con ("raster1"=="raster2"=="raster3"=="raster4"=="raster5"=="raster6"=="raster7"=="raster8"=="raster9"=="raster10"=="raster11"=="raster12","raster1",255)
```

In that statement, I use raster calculator. But, it is error.
Does anyone know how to perform this in ArcGIS?

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your conditional statement? What is it you wish to find out? It might be that there is a different way of approaching this.

Comment: I want to see that there are changes or not in each pixel. If there are no changes, so raster1=raster2...etc. And I want to see what pixel value that no changes. If there are changes, I want to give sign (for example I give value 255). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, I try other tool, and I get the answer. There are two steps. First, I use Equal To Frequency. I input raster1 for value raster. Then I input other raster for raster1 until raster12. For example the output raster is raster13. The value will be 0 until 12 depends on value among raster. If the value is 12, so raster1=raster2=raster3...etc. The second step, I use Raster Calculator. That is : Con("raster13"==12,"raster1",255). I hope this is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a list of == in the same conditional test. You need to link them with logical expressions.

Con ( (raster1== raster2) & (raster2==raster3) & ...

Comment: Great. It is work. Ok, there is a little problem. There are clouds and the value is zero. I want zero value is out from counting. How to perform this? Thanks.

Comment: same idea as before : ((raster1==raster2)|(raster1==0)|(raster2==0))&...

Comment: I have tried for ((raster1==raster2)|(raster1==0)|(raster2==0))&...  It is work, but it is not in order. I have tried for 6 raster. The value for raster1; raster2... are 0; 0; 0; 0.1; 0; 0.2. The result is 0. The result should 255. Because 0.1 is not the same as 0.2. Another value for raster1; raster2... are 0,2; 0,2; 0; 0,4; 0; 0,2. The result is 0,2. May be a little work to fix the this formula. Thanks.

Comment: Largely, this formula is true when I see the value. But, when one of the raster value is zero, sometimes the result is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You need indeed to test all combination (n(n-1)/2, that is 66 with n=12) in order to have your final result. There is certainly a better algorithm, but this is another question. For instance, you iterate through your file rasterOld

Comment: continued: rasterOld = Con( ((raster1==raster2)|(raster1==0)) , raster2 , 255 ); rasterOld = Con( ((rasterOld==raster3)|(rasterOld==0)) , raster3 , 255 );...

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [cell statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Cell_Statistics/009z0000007q000000/).  Where all the values are the same the variety statistic will be 1.